# Django error: type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'META'

Tags: django

I am new to django. I am coding a urlshortner now I wanted to ad functionality to read Http referer to count number of times the link has been clicked from various social platforms.

In documentation it states that HttpRequest object that in included in django.http will extract it using - HttpRequest.META['HTTP_REFERER']

So I did this to print out the type of info that it contains -

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
from .models import UrlSave

def display(request,id):
    print(HttpRequest.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
    try:
        short_url = UrlSave.objects.get(pk=id)
        visit_time = short_url.times_visited
        short_url.times_visited = short_url.times_visited+1
        url = short_url.to_view
        short_url.save()
        context = {'visit':visit_time,'url':url}
        return render(request,'shorturl/previsit.html',context)
    except:
        return HttpResponse('Wrong Url')
```

But when I visit the link it prints out the error in CLI - 
AttributeError: type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'META'

I am unable to find out the reason for it even after going through many stackoverflow pages
Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not obtain the `META` of the request by accessing it like a class attribute, the specific request is the `request` parameter, so you can access it with `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']`:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
from .models import UrlSave

def display(request, id):
    print(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
    try:
        short_url = UrlSave.objects.get(pk=id)
        visit_time = short_url.times_visited
        short_url.times_visited = short_url.times_visited+1
        url = short_url.to_view
        short_url.save()
        context = {'visit':visit_time,'url':url}
        return render(request,'shorturl/previsit.html',context)
    except:
        return HttpResponse('Wrong Url')
```

Comment: Although I figured it out just after posting this question, but thanks for your efforts. Furthur more I noticed that http referer is not getting flushed after the initial impact. What I mean is that when user first land on the my site's pre-redirection page and the counter is added by 1, if user just decied to refresh the page the referer is not flushed, it is still present and result in counter getting added again. It would be a great help, if you can guide me on this one.